# Overlapping image with footer - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a design here that is part of a website footer.
https://ibb.co/mBRpx7Y

The website has a box kind of layout with a dark background. But in the footer, at the bottom right corner, there is an extra image pattern comes which will overlap the content section and also covert the background part.

Right now, I used CSS to achieve this by adding two background images. The image position is correct but the image pattern does not appear on the white container because it is not transparent. Is there any way to achieve this?
Here is the sample code of what I have right now:

```css
body{
      background-image: url(https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/10-102760_dot-background-png.png),url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508615070457-7baeba4003ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80) !important;
    background-size: auto, cover!important;
    background-position: right bottom, left top!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
        background-attachment: scroll, scroll;
  
}

.container{
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin:0px auto;
}
.section1{
  min-height:200px;
  background: #b0f3ff;
  padding:50px;
}
.section2{
  min-height:150px;
  background: #fff;
  padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="section1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et mi ante. Etiam gravida tincidunt magna vestibulum rutrum. Phasellus a libero vulputate, malesuada nunc non, efficitur leo. Fusce porttitor nisl in fringilla lacinia. Fusce a sem sagittis enim imperdiet pretium at a diam. Aliquam et lacus quis augue sodales venenatis eu id justo. Phasellus et blandit felis. Proin in purus lectus.
</div>
<div class="section2">
Terms and Conditions
Privacy Policy
©2021 All rights reserve
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself, only including an externally hosted code link means that if the code changes/the site goes down/the URL breaks, your question will cease to make sense.

Comment: The expected output is here https://ibb.co/mBRpx7Y. If you see the background image is overlapping the content

Comment: You can use pseudo element on body e.g.: `body:after {}`. Make it absolute to bottom right corner and add this dotted background to it.

Comment: @Rahul do you want something like [this](https://codepen.io/ankitcodes/pen/VwMwZxm)?

Comment: @DBS Hey don't call him out for that, sometimes the code snippets are not easy to use, especially for a new user

Comment: @WebDevDude I politely informed the user of a requirement when posting a question, along with an explanation of why it's required (The question was 1 vote away from being closed before the snippet was added) I didn't "call him out"...

Comment: ok sure ig, sry dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pseudo element on body e.g.: `body:after {}`. Make it absolute to bottom right corner and add this dotted background to it instead of on `body`.

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508615070457-7baeba4003ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

body:after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/10-102760_dot-background-png.png);
    width: 380px;
    height: 384px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.section1 {
    min-height: 200px;
    background: #b0f3ff;
    padding: 50px;
}

.section2 {
    min-height: 150px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="section1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et mi ante. Etiam gravida tincidunt magna vestibulum rutrum. Phasellus a libero vulputate, malesuada nunc non, efficitur leo. Fusce porttitor nisl in fringilla lacinia. Fusce a sem sagittis enim imperdiet pretium at a diam. Aliquam et lacus quis augue sodales venenatis eu id justo. Phasellus et blandit felis. Proin in purus lectus.
    </div>
    <div class="section2">
        Terms and Conditions
        Privacy Policy
        ©2021 All rights reserve
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, nice! This is what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of effect you're looking for?

```css
.container{
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin:0px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.section1{
  min-height:200px;
  background: #b0f3ff;
  padding:50px;
}
.section2{
  min-height:150px;
  background: #fff;
  padding:50px;
}
.section3 {
  background-image: url(https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/10-102760_dot-background-png.png),url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508615070457-7baeba4003ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80) !important;
    background-size: auto, cover!important;
    background-position: right bottom, left top!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
        background-attachment: scroll, scroll;
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  z-index : 2;
  opacity:0.5;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section3" ></div>
<div class="section1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et mi ante. Etiam gravida tincidunt magna vestibulum rutrum. Phasellus a libero vulputate, malesuada nunc non, efficitur leo. Fusce porttitor nisl in fringilla lacinia. Fusce a sem sagittis enim imperdiet pretium at a diam. Aliquam et lacus quis augue sodales venenatis eu id justo. Phasellus et blandit felis. Proin in purus lectus.
</div>
<div class="section2">
Terms and Conditions
Privacy Policy
©2021 All rights reserve
</div>
</div>
```